# Post on Users Timeline when Login via Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I have an application where the user can login via Facebook. When he logs in the first time, it stores the email address in our database (the one we got from Facebook) and sends him a daily newsletter mail. This not so cool, because most user who log in via Facebook would prefer to have it in there stream instead of a mail.

Here my question: How can I post through the API to the users timeline. I couldn't find a manual, or is it just not possible?

(I'm using the https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook and rails, but my question is more general if it is possible via the facebook API)

Comment: thanks, that's what I did, but the answer I got below is much better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can post using "koala gem" to the users timeline.

Here is the documentation

```
https://github.com/arsduo/koala
```